# PHP Between X date and X Date break into periods of months

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

Making a report:

User inputs 2 dates: E.G start:04-03-12 end: 15-06-12

```
$ROStartDateTimestamp = strtotime('04-03-12');
$ROStartDate = date('d/m/Y', $ROStartDateTimestamp);
$ROEndDateTimestamp = strtotime('15-06-12');
$ROEndDate = date('d/m/Y', $ROEndDateTimestamp);
```

I want to break the periods down into months.

How do I find out;

1. How many days are in the start month?
2. Whats the date of the last day in the start month?
3. How many days between start date and end of the month?

Thanks Heep's :)

Comment: `date('t',...)` gives the number of days in a month. This gives you the number of days in start month and - obvious - the last date in that month (works with leap years).

Comment: Also take a look at the [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). It has way more options.

Comment: Thanks ............ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop it and create an array that later can be used with count or array_sum.

I create a multidimensional array with year month and day of all days between the start and end.

```
$start = strtotime('04-03-12');
$end = strtotime('15-06-12');

For($i = $start; $i<=$end;){
    List($y, $m, $d) = explode(" ", date("Y m d", $i));
    $arr[$y][$m][$d] = 1;
    $i += 86400;
}

Var_dump($arr);
```

The same thing can be done with DateTime but it's usually heavier to use, that is why I use strtotime.
https://3v4l.org/1m8aM

Comment: sorry for being dumb, but I haven't used lists before.

How do you index the list?

I've tried:

foreach($arr['y'] as $day){
$num = count($day[$m))
}

I've tried just $m etc can you please should me how you would count it,

Comment: You don't index a list. List() makes variables of an array. In this case the explode returns three values we know that for sure. And we also know the first is year then month and last day, so instead of getting a indexed array I used list to say the first item in the array call it $y, the next $m and the last item $d

Comment: sorry just edited post, see above, thanks for your help :) its going to do what I need to do as soon as I figure out how to count and find the last item in the day list for each month  :)

Comment: This is essentially the same code https://3v4l.org/OOEpf see that list makes it little easier to read and cleaner

Comment: Thanks but why does it say 4109? shouldn't it be 3 months between 03 and 06?

Comment: No, I used your code. Your code is wrong. How do you think me (or PHP) is supposed to know you want yy-mm-dd? Or is it yy-dd-mm? As I see it there is 9 possible combinations. You choosed a format that is incorrect/not parsable. Is the format important or can you change the format?

Comment: @JonnyB'Good Can you answer my question?

Comment: I think you got the wrong end of the stick, all i was trying to find out is how many months there was, but I think you totaled the days instead, anyways, thanks for your help. all sorted

Answer (score 0):

```
$ROStartDateTimestamp = strtotime('04-03-12');
$ROStartDate = date('d/m/Y', $ROStartDateTimestamp);
$ROEndDateTimestamp = strtotime('15-06-12');
$ROEndDate = date('d/m/Y', $ROEndDateTimestamp);

//To find month in start date:
$ROMonthofStartDate = date('m',$ROStartDateTimestamp);

//To find year in start date:
$ROYearofStartDate = date('Y',$ROStartDateTimestamp);

//To find number of days in a month:
$numDaysInMonthofStartDate=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$ROMonthofStartDate,$ROYearofStartDate);

//To find last date of month:
$lastDateInMonthofStartDate=date('Y-m-t',$ROStartDateTimestamp);
$lastDateTimestamp = strtotime($lastDateInMonthofStartDate);

//To find number of days from start date to the end of month:
$numDaysFromStartToEndDate = round( ($lastDateTimestamp-$ROStartDateTimestamp) / (60 * 60 * 24));

echo $numDaysFromStartToEndDate;
```

Comment: Mind that `$ROStartDate` is a string date and it will not work with date the way you wrote the code

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I have now used `$ROStartDateTimestamp` instead of `$ROStartDate`.